# Mui custom step not rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the mui stepper but I have a problem, my step does not render.

My stepper is in a dialog :

```js
const DialogForm = ({ open, activeStep, children }: {
  open: boolean;
  activeStep: number;
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];}

) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(open);
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={isOpen}
      PaperProps={{
        sx: dialogPaperStyle,
      }}
    >
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} connector={null} orientation="vertical" sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        {children}
      </Stepper>
    </Dialog>
  );
};


DialogForm.Step = QCStep;
```

And each step body is a children of :

```js
const QCStep = ({ children }: {children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];}) => {
  const stepProps: { completed?: boolean } = {};
  console.log(children);
  return (
    <Step {...stepProps}>
      <StepContent sx={stepContentStyle}>
        <> {children} </>
      </StepContent>
    </Step>
  );
};
```

And I try to create my steps but they don’t appear, but if I delete my stepContent, all my steps appear afterwards

```js
<DialogForm open={true} activeStep={activeStep}>
  <DialogForm.Step>
    {'COUCOU'}
    </QCDialogForm.Step>
    <DialogForm.Step>
    <TextField placeholder={'placeholder'}  />
  </DialogForm.Step>
</DialogForm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find a solution by mapping my children and by putting my step and stepContent components in the same file as the stepper component:

```js
const DialogForm = ({ open, activeStep, children }: {
  open: boolean;
  activeStep: number;
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];}

) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(open);
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={isOpen}
      PaperProps={{
        sx: dialogPaperStyle,
      }}
    >

      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} connector={null} orientation="vertical" sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        {children.map((child, index) => {
          return (
            <Step key={index} active={index === activeStep}>
              <StepContent sx={stepContentStyle} TransitionComponent={Collapse}>
                {child}
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

And my children are all my steps